# How does MongoDb sort work with list, empty list and null values?

Tags: list, mongodb, sorting, null, empty-list

We are using MongoDB 2.4.9 locally on our Ubuntu 12.04 machine. We put the following queries into mongo console (db.a is an empty collection):

```
> db.a.insert({'a': null})
> db.a.insert({'a': [null]})
> db.a.insert({'a': null})
> db.a.insert({'a': []})
> db.a.insert({'a': [[]]})

> db.a.find().sort({'a': 1})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52de6dd4ff91f5efcb1efacc"), "a" : [ ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52de6dbaff91f5efcb1efac9"), "a" : null }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52de6dbeff91f5efcb1efaca"), "a" : [  null ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52de6dc8ff91f5efcb1efacb"), "a" : null }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52de6debff91f5efcb1efacd"), "a" : [  [ ] ] }
```

We are following http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort which sets order of types as:

```
MinKey (internal type)
Null
Numbers (ints, longs, doubles)
Symbol, String
Object
Array
...
```

So I would expect the result be:

```
null
null
[]
[null]
[[]]
```

Based on several more queries we made a hypothesis that instead of `array`s, their first element is compared (including type of it). In case of equality `ObjectId` is used. But according to the type order nothing but the internal `MinKey` should be before `null`. 
So how does MongoDb sort value in reality?

P.S. As mongo is open source an answer should be somewhere here: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/tree/master